# strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime-format

I want to convert every row form the historical['startTime'] column to dates but it is showing an error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import datetime

historical = requests.get('https://ftx.com/api/markets/usdt-perp/candles?resolution=14400&start_time=1309062800').json()

historical = pd.DataFrame(historical['result'])
historical['startTime'] = datetime.strptime(historical['startTime'], '%d/%m/%y %H')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting `startTime` in string, so lets first convert that to datetime objects.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

historical = requests.get(
    'https://ftx.com/api/markets/usdt-perp/candles?resolution=14400&start_time=1309062800').json()
historical = pd.DataFrame(historical['result'])

historical['startTime'] = pd.to_datetime(
    historical['startTime']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%y %H')


print(historical)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach which doesn't require the datetime library at all

```
historical['startTime'] = list([pd.to_datetime(x, format='%d/%m/%y %H') for x in historical['startTime'].to_list()])
```